# My Code wont replace the html strings properly?

Tags: java, android

My current code:

```
a= a.replace("&#039;", "'");
a = android.text.Html.fromHtml(a).toString();
```

The issue is its still outputting this:

```
Magician&#039;s
```

Though it is replacing most of the html it doesn't replace all of it. how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this:

```
System.out.println("it&#039;s working".replaceAll("&#039;", "'"));
```

and it prints out this:

```
it's working
```

Answer (score 0):

`replaceAll` takes a regex as argument, try [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace)

Comment: The method signature for replace is `(char, char)` so you can't just use it instead of `replaceAll`.

Comment: There is also a `replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` `String` implements the `CharSequence` interface

Comment: Thanks for responding, I haven't encountered that one before, good to know.

Answer (score 0):

//try this

```
String parsingStr="&#039";

a= a.replaceAll(getXMLString(parsingStr), "'");  //convert your special char here
a = android.text.Html.fromHtml(a).toString();

public static String getXMLString(String str)
    {
        if(str.contains("&"))
        {
            str = str.replace("&", "&amp;");
        }else if (str.contains("<"))
        {
            str = str.replace("<", "&lt;");
        }else if (str.contains(">"))
        {
            str = str.replace(">", "&gt;");
        }else if (str.contains("'"))
        {
            str = str.replace("'", "&apos;");
        }else if (str.contains("\""))
        {
            str = str.replace("\"", "&quot;");
        }

        return str;
    }
```

Comment: The original poster is looking to do the opposite of this code and replace entities with characters.